# how to add new column to model which is referenced to other model by foreign key in django

Tags: python, django

I have a model named Shape:

```
class Shape(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
```

and another model named Tank which has Shape model as foreignkey:

```
def get_default(model):
    value, is_created = model.objects.get_or_create(name=0)
    return value.id

class Tank(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shape = models.ForeignKey(Shape, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                          default=get_default(Shape),
                          related_name="tanks")
```

when i try to add a new column(with null=True) in Shape model, at `python manage.py makemigrations` django raises a error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: tank_shape.Column name`

Comment: did you try `python manage.py makemigrations; python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @pissall that error raises on python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: Could you share a traceback? And a line in code that it links to?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych
`File "/media/prince/7BD7C716141DF4EB/waltr/waltrapp/tank/models.py", line 80, in <module>
    class Tank(models.Model):
  File "/media/prince/7BD7C716141DF4EB/waltr/waltrapp/tank/models.py", line 90, in Tank
    default=get_default(Shape),
  File "/media/prince/7BD7C716141DF4EB/waltr/waltrapp/tank/models.py", line 76, in get_default
    value, is_created = model.objects.get_or_create(name=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this following line, for `default` argument, you call a function to get the default of `Shape` model:

```
shape = models.ForeignKey(Shape, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                          default=get_default(Shape),
                          related_name="tanks")
```

But the `Shape` model variable `name` doesn't have a default. And `Shape` will not have a default by itself right. A field in the `Shape` table is going to have a default, for eg. `name`. :

```
# Your code
name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
```

To get the default value, you can use:

`Shape._meta.get_field('name').get_default()`

Based on your recent comment, try change to the following code:

```
shape = models.ForeignKey(Shape, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                          related_name="tanks")
```

## EDIT:

Giving full code as answer:

```
class Shape(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

class Tank(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shape = models.ForeignKey(Shape, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                          default=1,
                          related_name="tanks")
```

Comment: Could you please explain, why does `name` need a default value? The value for `name` is provided in `get_or_create`

Comment: yup, i have same question as Yevhen , as i have given 0 value for name,`value, is_created = model.objects.get_or_create(name=0)` why do i need to provide default

Comment: `name` doesn't need a default value. But when you say `get_default` on `Shape`, it cannot find a default value for `Shape`

Comment: Well. It should create it, shouldn't it? Hence the name `get_or_create`. I'm a bit concerned with passing `0` (int) to `CharField`, but that shouldn't produce this error.

Comment: `get_or_create` has no relation with the `default` key in `CharField`. It means, if no value is passed to `get_or_create`, what will be the default value to be used. And yes, I ignored the fact that 0 was being passed to a `CharField` focusing on the problem on hand.

Comment: `get_or_create` as the name suggests, will look for `name == 0`, if it exists then get the object or else create it and get it.

Comment: No it is creating object, with value passed as 0. I had checked it already. @pissall acc. To you i should use `default=Shape._meta.get_field('name').get_default()` in Tank.shape column?

Comment: Just use `shape = models.ForeignKey(Shape, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
                          related_name="tanks")` and tell me if it works

Comment: @pissall it raises error: `ERRORS:
tank.Tank.shape: (fields.E321) Field specifies on_delete=SET_DEFAULT, but has no default value.
        HINT: Set a default value, or change the on_delete rule`

Comment: Change the on_delete to CASCADE

Comment: @pissall i can add column after changing it to CASCADE, but as you know i don't want CASCADE.

Comment: Then please give a default, I'll revise my answer

Comment: gave default as before @pissall

Comment: Updated my answer @Prince777

Comment: How is this an answer? What if there is no `Shape` with `pk=1`? Why use an integer for default of `CharField`? And `default` in `shape` `ForeignKey` does not reference default of `name`, it references `Shape` with `pk=1`.
That is a harmful misinformation.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych There is no `get_or_create` in this model. What we are saying, `Shape` doesn't need `default=1`. When a `Shape` is deleted, user doesn't want `Tanks` belonging to it to be deleted. So they default to a value which is given in the `ForeignKey` definition. Also, the `1` value is the `id` and not `Shape.name`. `id` that is autogenerated by Django which is autoincremental. It will take the last nonexisting entry number

Comment: So what if there is no `Shape` with `id` == 1? It can happen it was deleted.

Comment: Doesn't matter if there is no `Shape` with `id`=1. If there was a Shape called "Square", which was a foreign key to 5 `Tanks`. Then if that `Shape` is deleted, then you don't want to deleted the `Tanks` belonging to it. So you say, when a `Shape` is deleted, set the foreign key `Shape` value for the belonging `Tanks` as a default value. Which is `1`, and if `1` already exists then go to `2` taking the smallest available number.

Comment: The default value of `shape` might reference non-existing `Shape`. In other words: if `Shape` with `id` == 1 does not exist, after deleting "Squere", 5 `Tanks` will reference non-existing `Shape`.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Yes, 5 `Tanks` will reference a non-existing `Shape`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200387/discussion-between-yevhen-kuzmovych-and-pissall).